# How I can erase datacontract XLMS from a WCF?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm trying to send a soap request to a WCF service. I'm triying to generate the Soap request using the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage() method, but I get this xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <h:AuthHeader xmlns:h="http://schemas.multi-mit.com/SLMi5" xmlns="http://schemas.multi-mit.com/SLMi5" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Username>GMMX166821</Username>
         <Password>Password1</Password>
      </h:AuthHeader>
      <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Created xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LeadIt">2016-06-02T17:25:38.5022598Z</Created>
         <Expires xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LeadIt">2016-06-02T17:30:37.5022598Z</Expires>
      </Timestamp>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <usernameToken xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LeadIt">
            <Password>SonicRS2017</Password>
            <Username>cheval</Username>
         </usernameToken>
      </Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <GetLead xmlns="http://schemas.multi-mit.com/SLMi5">
         <LeadID>123456</LeadID>
      </GetLead>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

the thing is, that the webservice is returning an error, I try to debug the xml, and the error is this part `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LeadIt"` and `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";` is it possible to erase that part?

The code I use to generate the headers is

```cs
Security security = new Security();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp();

MessageHeader time = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Timestamp","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", timestamp);
MessageHeader secu = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", security);

request.Headers.Add(time);
request.Headers.Add(secu);

public class Timestamp
{
  public DateTime Created;
  public DateTime Expires;

  public Timestamp()
  {
    Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(299);
  }
}

public class Security
{
  public Security()
  {
    usernameToken = new UsernameToken();
  }

  private UsernameToken usernameToken;

  public UsernameToken UsernameToken
  {
    get
    {
      return usernameToken;
    }
    set
    {
      usernameToken = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I try to use `[DataContract(Namespace = "")]` but when I try it doesn't appear the content of the node timestamp and security, hope you can help me, and sorry for my bad english, is not my first language

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to send a soap request to a WCF service

There are a number of ways you can consume a WCF service from a WCF client, none of which should involve writing the soap wrapper yourself. The WCF framework is designed to insulate you from having to do this.

You can either consume the service directly using ChannelFactory or if available, generate a proxy by consuming the service metadata.